# Time and gravity relation

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time, gravitational-redshift

I was reading about relativity when I crossed by the applications of relativity in real life, and they said that as the elevation increase time increase so gravity decrease

Can someone explain to me, why this happen? What's the relation between gravity and time?

Comment: That's called [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation). Did you try searching for this first?

Comment: Time dilation is unrelated to the fact that gravity decreases, and it can be observed at small heights, where the difference in gravity isn't noticeable.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Comment: @Alfred Centuari Though unclear,this question is not useless,and shows the curiosity of the person seeking the answer.

Comment: @SahilChadha, hover your cursor over the downvote button.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called gravitational time dilation.If you have a spherically symmetric centre of attraction like earth or sun,then you will find that clocks that are closer to the centre tick more slowly as compared to clocks that are far away .This effect is crucial in design of GPS satellites for if this effect is not taken into account satellite and earth clock will differ by about 50000 nanoseconds in a day,causing a discrepancy of 11km in position o earth rendering the setup useless.